Blank page after connecting react page with GitHub
I was trying to launch my React web page using GitHub pages and now it does not load anything showing a blank page.

As seen on the page or here: https://kirubelyonas.github.io/Portfolio/. I have no clue what's wrong with my website.
I was connecting my React page with GitHub pages everything was working but when I launched the page it became a blank page I checked my "homepage": "https://<Username>.github.io/<Repository-name>", tried using <HashRouter> and don't have any other clue to what's happening.

It looks like it's a casing problem.
When I try to fetch https://kirubelyonas.github.io/portfolio/static/js/main.272016d6.js as your site does, I get a 404, but when I try to fetch https://kirubelyonas.github.io/Portfolio/static/js/main.272016d6.js it loads normally.
Your repo is Portfolio with an upper case P, but in package.json you have
  "homepage": "https://KirubelYonas.github.io/portfolio",
  "name": "portfolio",

I believe renaming the repo portfolio or changing homepage to Portfolio should fix it for you.

I have tried it before posting this question.
